# Как выполнить команды с ожиданием?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите как разграничить выполнение команд, чтобы сначала выполнить удаление ключа в реестре, затем запуск внешнего приложения, после чего, в реестр должны вернуться параметры, и приложение завершит работу.

Это нужно для того, чтобы команда для удаления ключа реестра успела выполнить действия до открытия внешнего приложения, а приложение успело запуститься до возвращения параметров реестра в исходное состояние.

Как это работает - файл переносится на приложение, приложение считывает аргументы файла, далее по коду:

```
if (args.Any())
{
     key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("MyAapp\\BranchReg", true);
     key.DeleteValue("KeyReg", false);
     key.Close();

     Process.Start(args[0]);

     key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("MyAapp\\BranchReg");
     key.SetValue("KeyReg", "");
     key.Close();

     Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Если вам нужна синхронизация процессов, вы можете попробовать использовать какой-нибудь тип глобальной блокировки, например [мьютекс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Если приложение с GUI, можно использовать `WaitForInputIdle`. Также см. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6390030/5045688

Answer (score 3):

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: К сожалению `WaitForExit` приведет к тому, что приложение начнет ожидать завершения процесса внешнего приложения, и только потом вернет параметры реестра в исходное состояние...

Comment: @Vitokhv, как я понял, надо чтобы значение изменилось в "" только после того, как приложение которое мы запускаем сделает что-то, но при этом оно может продолжать свою работу т.е. его ожидание нам не подходит. тогда как вариант может пытаться получить значение в цикле после запуска из необходимой ветви и после того, как значение будет успешно получено изменять его на "". ну или смотреть в сторону RegNotifyChangeKeyValue

Comment: Все чего я опасаюсь, что код может случайно опередить запуск внешнего приложения, допустим, внешнее приложение еще не успело запуститься, а параметр реестра уже вернулся в исходное состояние.

Comment: Что насчет `Thread.Sleep(10);` думаю 10 миллисекунд будет достаточно, чтобы отделить команды хотя бы временем. Но жалуются на данный способ (вроде могут быть ошибки).

Comment: на счет Sleep, это типа задел для будущей "оптимизации"